# Saving A Model That Contains Universal Sentence Encoder as its Embedding

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, tensorflow-hub

I am trying to save a model which uses USE from tf-hub as its embedding layer and has a few FFN stacked upon it. The model seems to work fine, but I am facing a problem in saving and loading the model.

```
disable_eager_execution()

embed = hub.Module(module_url)

def UniversalEmbedding(x):
    return embed(tf.squeeze(tf.cast(x, tf.string)))

input_text = Input(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)
response_text = Input(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)

text_embedding = Lambda(UniversalEmbedding, output_shape=(512, ))(input_text)

response_embedding = Lambda(UniversalEmbedding, output_shape=(512, ))(response_text)

response_embedding = Dense(512, activation='relu')(response_embedding)
response_embedding = Dense(512, activation='relu')(response_embedding)

score = Dot(axes=1, normalize=True)([text_embedding, response_embedding])

pred = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(score)

text_encoder = Model(inputs=[input_text], outputs=text_embedding)
response_encoder = Model(inputs=[response_text], outputs=response_embedding)
model = Model(inputs=[input_text, response_text], outputs=pred)
```

The code above is how I built my model (its a dual encoder model with USE as its encoder).

**I had to disable eager execution because USE seems to be not working in eager execution environment yet. If not, and if there is a workaround for that, I'd really appreciate any help for this too :)**

The model is trained and saved via the following code :

```py
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as session:
    K.set_session(session)
    session.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())  
    session.run(tf.compat.v1.tables_initializer())
    history = model.fit_generator(generator=train_neg_sample_generator, 
                                  validation_data=val_neg_sample_generator, epochs=20,
                                  callbacks=[checkpointer, earlystopper], verbose=0)
```

and the model is loaded with no error when the weights in the checkpoints (saved in hdf5 files) are loaded to the model defined in the code above. So the code below works fine, only because the architecture 'model' is already defined above.

```py
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as session:
    K.set_session(session)
    session.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
    session.run(tf.compat.v1.tables_initializer())
    model.load_weights('./saved_models/weights.03-0.29.hdf5') 
    tf.keras.models.save_model(model, 'test_model2.hdf5') 
    predicts = model.predict([["how are you?", "how are you?", 'hi', 'my two favorites in one pic!'], ["i'm fine", "what the heck", 'hi', 'same!']])
    print(predicts)
    print(np.argmax(predicts, axis=1))
```

Then I tried 2 things. First, I tried to save the architecture in json format, load the model architecture and then load the weights, but it did not work. Then I tried to save the whole model via keras.models.save_model, but it did not work either.

In both cases, they returned 
**AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'**

How can I save/load the whole model (if not at once, loading architecture / weight separately is fine too) ?

Here is the whole error log

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-47468f2533ad> in <module>()
      1 from keras.models import load_model
      2 
----> 3 model2 = load_model('testest.h5')

13 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py in load_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    456                 os.remove(tmp_filepath)
    457             return res
--> 458         return load_function(*args, **kwargs)
    459 
    460     return load_wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    548     if H5Dict.is_supported_type(filepath):
    549         with H5Dict(filepath, mode='r') as h5dict:
--> 550             model = _deserialize_model(h5dict, custom_objects, compile)
    551     elif hasattr(filepath, 'write') and callable(filepath.write):
    552         def load_function(h5file):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py in _deserialize_model(h5dict, custom_objects, compile)
    241         raise ValueError('No model found in config.')
    242     model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
--> 243     model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
    244     model_weights_group = h5dict['model_weights']
    245 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py in model_from_config(config, custom_objects)
    591                         '`Sequential.from_config(config)`?')
    592     from ..layers import deserialize
--> 593     return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
    594 
    595 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
    166                                     module_objects=globs,
    167                                     custom_objects=custom_objects,
--> 168                                     printable_module_name='layer')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    145                     config['config'],
    146                     custom_objects=dict(list(_GLOBAL_CUSTOM_OBJECTS.items()) +
--> 147                                         list(custom_objects.items())))
    148             with CustomObjectScope(custom_objects):
    149                 return cls.from_config(config['config'])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in from_config(cls, config, custom_objects)
   1041         # First, we create all layers and enqueue nodes to be processed
   1042         for layer_data in config['layers']:
-> 1043             process_layer(layer_data)
   1044 
   1045         # Then we process nodes in order of layer depth.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in process_layer(layer_data)
   1027 
   1028             layer = deserialize_layer(layer_data,
-> 1029                                       custom_objects=custom_objects)
   1030             created_layers[layer_name] = layer
   1031 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
    166                                     module_objects=globs,
    167                                     custom_objects=custom_objects,
--> 168                                     printable_module_name='layer')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    147                                         list(custom_objects.items())))
    148             with CustomObjectScope(custom_objects):
--> 149                 return cls.from_config(config['config'])
    150         else:
    151             # Then `cls` may be a function returning a class.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in from_config(cls, config)
   1101             A layer instance.
   1102         """
-> 1103         return cls(**config)
   1104 
   1105     def count_params(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_layer.py in __init__(self, input_shape, batch_size, batch_input_shape, dtype, input_tensor, sparse, name)
     85                                          dtype=dtype,
     86                                          sparse=self.sparse,
---> 87                                          name=self.name)
     88         else:
     89             self.is_placeholder = False

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in placeholder(shape, ndim, dtype, sparse, name)
    539         x = tf.sparse_placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
    540     else:
--> 541         x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
    542     x._keras_shape = shape
    543     x._uses_learning_phase = False

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked fine with tensorflow version 1.15
Looking forward for tf-hub to become completely compatible with tensorflow 2.0 and keras...

Answer (score 0):

Provide the whole error log, not just a part of it.

If it's really error because of saving then what about `model.save('model.h5')`?
Not using the module from `tf.keras.models` but call a methomd from the `Model` class itself.

But why these code?

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as session:
    K.set_session(session)
    session.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
    session.run(tf.compat.v1.tables_initializer())
```

I believe you could juat call `model.fit` right away, and your `tf` is version2 right? Why call `compat.v1`?

Tensorflow 2 doesn't have `Placeholder` so I think it's maybe about this.

Comment: The error appears when executing 
`model2 = load_model('testest.h5')`

Yes I am using tf version2, but some of the modules provided in tf-hub (like USE) don't seem work in eager execution.

Comment: For instance, if I call model.fit rigth away, it returns **FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value module_1/Encoder_en/Transformer/TransformerEncodeFast/encoder/layer_4/self_attention/multihead_attention/v/kernel
  [[{{node lambda_3/module_1_apply_default/Encoder_en/Transformer/TransformerEncodeFast/encoder/layer_4/self_attention/multihead_attention/v/kernel/read}}]]**
So the dilemma (if I am right) here is that to train model using USE, I need to use session as in older tf version, but to load the model I should not.